# openCV: creating a match of features, meaning of output array, java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

The following code (written in **Java** using **openCV**-libraries for *Image Processing*) produces an output of class **MatOfDMatch**. The problem is i dont understand what the values inside the array are telling me about the match:

```
FeatureDetector fastFeatureDetector = FeatureDetector
    .create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
DescriptorExtractor surfDescriptorExtractor = DescriptorExtractor
    .create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF); 
DescriptorMatcher flannDescriptorMatcher = DescriptorMatcher
    .create(DescriptorMatcher.FLANNBASED);

Mat image1 = Highgui.imread(myPicPath);
Mat image2 = Highgui.imread(myPicPath2);

ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint> keypoints1 = new ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint>();
    keypoints1.add(new MatOfKeyPoint());
ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint> keypoints2 = new ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint>();
    keypoints2.add(new MatOfKeyPoint());

fastFeatureDetector.detect(image1, keypoints1.get(0));
fastFeatureDetector.detect(image2, keypoints2.get(0));

Mat descriptor1 = new Mat();
Mat descriptor2 = new Mat();

surfDescriptorExtractor.compute(image1, keypoints1.get(0),
    descriptor1);
surfDescriptorExtractor.compute(image2, keypoints2.get(0),
    descriptor2);

ArrayList<MatOfDMatch> matches = new ArrayList<MatOfDMatch>();
matches.add(new MatOfDMatch());

flannDescriptorMatcher.match(descriptor1,
    descriptor2, matches.get(0));

Mat outImg = new Mat();
Features2d.drawMatches(image1, keypoints1.get(0), image2,
        keypoints2.get(0), matches.get(0), outImg,
        new Scalar(0, 255, 0), new Scalar(0, 0, 255), new MatOfByte(),
        Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

Highgui.imwrite(myOutpuPicPath,
            outImg);

//The following code part is not part of the Matching process (which is above part), 
//I include it here because it prints the MatOfDMatchvalues in a readable fashion
ArrayList<Double> matchChannel_0 = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> matchChannel_1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> matchChannel_2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> matchChannel_3 = new ArrayList<Double>();

for (int j = 0; j < matches.get(0).size().height; j++) {
matchChannel_0.add(matches.get(0).get(j, 0)[0]);
matchChannel_1.add(matches.get(0).get(j, 0)[1]);
    matchChannel_2.add(matches.get(0).get(j, 0)[2]);
matchChannel_3.add(matches.get(0).get(j, 0)[3]);
}

System.out.println(matchChannel_0 + "\n" + matchChannel_1 + "\n"
    + matchChannel_2 + "\n" + matchChannel_3);
```

Setting **image1** and **image2** to the **same pic**, lets all values in `matchChannel_1` become as `matchChannel_0` and values `matchChannel_3` become all 0.

Setting **image1** and **image2** to **different pictures**, the values become different.

**What do the values mean?** They sure have to tell **something about the match**, but i cant figure out what exactly and how. *I need an answer like "bigger values in that channel means this and in the other channel that".* Could someone clarify this, as it is not explained by the openCV tutorial on this [page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html).

Comment: please explain what is wrong with the post, before downvoting it

Comment: I guess your question is vague (I didn't downvote). I suggest you study the source code of `MatOfDMatch` and/or apply more tests (different pics, same pics, similar pics, less similar pics) to implicitly understand the code.

Comment: @kiltek Im also very confused with MatOfDMatch. I googled a lot but didn't find any thing that describe how we can use it to analyse matching between training and query image. If you have any update please share.